# Why Angular is calling my function... dozens of times?

Tags: angular

My `AuthService` is used for authentication purposes; once user is logged in, `user` property returns the `User` instance (notice the `console.log`):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // ...

  get user(): null | User {
    console.log('Calling getUser()');
    const decodedToken: { sub: {} } | null = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.authToken);
    if (!decodedToken) {
      return null;
    }

    return plainToClass(User, decodedToken.sub);
  }
}
```

I basically call `authService.user` only one time in `header-component.html`:

```
<!--- ... --->
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['logout']">Logout ({{ authService.user.username }})</a>
```

**Question**: JavaScript console shows dozens of times *Calling getUser()* when **I refresh the page**. How this is possible? Who is calling `authService.user` so many times?

[image]

**`AuthService` ref 1**: in `app.modules.ts`

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  jwtOptionsProvider: {
    provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: (authService: AuthService) => {
      return { tokenGetter: () => authService.authToken };
    },
    deps: [AuthService]
  }
}),
```

**`AuthService` ref 2**: in `core.module.ts` as provider:

```
providers: [
    // ...
    AuthService
],
```

**`AuthService` ref 3**: injected in `HeaderComponent`:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(readonly authService: AuthService) { }
}
```

**`AuthService` ref 4**: injected in `LoginComponent`:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
```

**`AuthService` ref 5**: injected in `LogoutComponent`:

```
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
}
```

Comment: If you call a function from the template, it will be invoked every time zone runs change detection

Comment: @user184994 can you explain me better? I edited the question, this is happening refreshing the page, not when angular detect changes in the source.

Comment: You'll notice that when you change properties, Angular automatically updates your HTML file for you. It will frequently check was has changed so that it can update the template for you, but in order to do so, it needs to call that function again. Bear in mind it will run change detection just to check if anything has changed, it may run several times even if nothing has changed.

Comment: @user184994 So it's model change detection that triggers the call... so many times? Is there something I can do to avoid it?

Comment: You can change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `ON_PUSH`, but it may not be what you want. You may be better calling that function once in `ngOnInit`, storing the result as a variable, and pointing your template at that variable instead.

Comment: @user184994 so assigning the result to a template variable will limit the change detection?

Comment: No, but it won't need to execute the function each time, it can simply use the stored variable